# view controller with nib subview nil

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a view controller with a nib file and want to show only that custom view in my MainViewController.

I instantiate the ViewController

```
var addViewC = addViewController(nibName:"addViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) as addViewController
```

adjust the frame

```
addViewC.view.frame = self.view.frame
```

and add the view

```
self.view.addSubview(addViewC.view);
```

In the nib file is a view and two textfields. Every thing is visible.
I can get the textfields over the outlets but the view(background) is always nil.
Can anybody tell me why? And how to change this!

the nib (I can't get the red view):
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set you the `view` outlet of your Files Owner?

Comment: I add a picture of the referencing outlets. addviewView is the outlet i dragged to the code of my controller.